# Calling method with OR w/o arguments?

Tags: python, arguments

Is there a way to shorten this OR skip the if-else check :

```
 if kv is None : self.obj.generate()
 else : self.obj.generate(**kv)
```

Comment: `self.obj.generate(**(kv or {}))`

Comment: thanks .. the bad thing it has to be None, not {}   ;(

Answer (score 1):

as easy as that:

`self.obj.generate() if not kv else self.obj.generate(**kv)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
li = [{},kv]
self.obj.generate(**li[bool(kv)])
```

1. You generate a 2-element list for your 2 outcomes.
2. You call your method using one of the two elements in your list; bool(kv) is your switch.

bool(kv) becomes False (which is equivalent to 0) if kv is None (or 0)

bool(kv) becomes True (which is equivalent to 1) if kv is anything other than None

Of course, you can do the whole thing in one line:

```
self.obj.generate(**[{},kv][bool(kv)])
```